# Stop a timer before it checks a parameter

Tags: c#, timer

I have a timer that performs an action every 2 hours, and I want to be able to stop the timer when a user unchecks a checkbox, and then provide feedback to a listbox.

The issue I am having is that while this code works, it will only update the listbox when it next gets to the 2 hour check.

Is it possible to get this to instantly stop when the checkbox is unchecked?

```
private void AutoRestart()
{
    if (AutoRScb.Checked.Equals(true))
    {
        var timeToWait = double.Parse(textBox1.Text) * 1000;

        var aTimer = new Timer();
        aTimer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
        aTimer.Interval = timeToWait;
        aTimer.Enabled = true;

        if (AutoRScb.Checked.Equals(false))
        {
            aTimer.Stop();
            aTimer.Dispose();
            UpdateList("auto restarts dead");
        }

        void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs elapsed)
        {
            try
            {
                foreach (var procs in Process.GetProcessesByName(comboBox2.Text))
                    procs.Kill();
                Thread.Sleep(1000);

                var proc = new Process();
                proc.StartInfo.FileName = textBox4.Text;

                if (textBox8.Text.Length > 0)
                    proc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = textBox8.Text;

                proc.Start();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just listen to the click event of the checkbox and perform your actions and checkings.

Comment: Could you expand on that a bit please? :)

Comment: Instead of periodically checking something, you can run your checks *when* something happens, in this case when you checkbox gets changed (clicked). You can write an event handler for that just as you would for a simple button.

Comment: I think the best approach is moving your timer outside the method. In this way you can reach its properties/methods from other places such as a UI event handler (for the checkbox). In other word you can maintein your logic and in the onclick event handler of the checkbox stop the timer...

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

I have this on the checked changed EH of the checkbox.

```
       private void AutoRScb_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (AutoRScb.Checked.Equals(true) && textBox1.Text.Length > 0)
        {
            var timeToWait = double.Parse(textBox1.Text) * 1000;
            rsTimer.Interval = timeToWait;
            rsTimer.Enabled = true;
        }
        if (AutoRScb.Checked.Equals(false))
        {
            rsTimer.Stop();
            rsTimer.Dispose();
        }


        if (rsTimer.Enabled == true)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("enabled");
            rsTimer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
            void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs elapsed)
            {
                try
                {
                    foreach (var procs in Process.GetProcessesByName(comboBox2.Text))
                        procs.Kill();
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);

                    var proc = new Process();
                    proc.StartInfo.FileName = textBox4.Text;

                    if (textBox8.Text.Length > 0)
                        proc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = textBox8.Text;

                    proc.Start();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex);
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }
        if (rsTimer.Enabled == false)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("disabled");
        }
    }
```

and this in the form:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    Timer rsTimer = new Timer();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd wrap the timer with a thing that checks whether the checkbox is checked, and if it's unchecked it'll stop trying to run the task:

```
int Ticks = 0, TickLimit = 1000;
void StartTimer()
{
   if (Checkbox.Checked.Equals(true))
   {
      var timeToWait = double.Parse(1000);
      var aTimer = new Timer();
      aTimer.Elapsed += OnTimedEventCheck;
      aTimer.Interval = timeToWait;
      aTimer.Enabled = true;
   }
}

void OnTimedEventCheck(object source, ElapsedEventArgs elapsed)
{
   ++Ticks;
   if (AutoRScb.Checked.Equals(false))
   {
      aTimer.Stop();
      aTimer.Dispose();
      UpdateList("auto restarts dead");
   }
   else if (Ticks >= TickLimit)
   { MyTimedEvent(); Ticks = 0; }
}

void MyTimedEvent()
{ 
   //Your stuff here
}
```

You'll need to do some math to figure out what to set the TickLimit to. If the timer checks once per second, you'll need the TickLimit to be set to 7200 for two hours.